# Golang Private Modules (v1.17) -- package found but does not contain the package

Tags: go

Reviewing numerous articles, running into this issue:

1. Created a private package, 'mypackage' in my git account
2. In git, I have MyCompany/mypackage
3. In another project, I want to import the package:

   ```golang
   ...
   import (
      "github.com/MyCompany/mypackage'
   )
   ```
4. When I run:

   ```
   go mod tidy
   ```

I get the following error:

github.com/MyCompany/mypackage: module github.com/MyCompany/mypackage@latest found (v0.0.0-20220126203606-a88fea44b771), but does not contain package github.com/MyCompany/mypackage

Not sure how to resolve this.

In my .gitconfig I have:

```
[url "ssh://git@github.com/"]
    insteadOf = https://github.com/
```

```
go env
```

shows these settings:

```
GOPRIVATE="github.com/MyCompany/*"
GONOPROXY="github.com/MyCompany/*"
GONOSUMDB="github.com/MyCompany/*"
```

What other configurations am I missing?

The go.mod file looks like:

```
module github.com/MyCompany/mypackage

go 1.17

require (
    github.com/go-redis/redis/v8 v8.11.4
    github.com/pkg/errors v0.9.1
)

require (
    github.com/cespare/xxhash/v2 v2.1.2 // indirect
    github.com/dgryski/go-rendezvous v0.0.0-20200823014737-9f7001d12a5f // indirect
)
```

Comment: What does the `go.mod` of the imported packaged look like?

Comment: added the go.mod file above so it formats okay

Answer (score 1):

Added a semver tag  (git tag v1.0.0, git push --tags) then was able to download