# How does one upgrade go project made for 1.9 to be compatiable with 1.18?

Tags: go

I'm trying to upgrade a go-project that was made for >= 1.9, but apperantly doesn't work with 1.18 due to lacking go.mod file, aka the lock for deps.

How do I properly upgrade it?

Original source code is at: https://github.com/annttu/latenssi-go

I'm getting a bunch of does not contain package and I don't understand as to why?

```
GOROOT=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.18/libexec #gosetup
GOPATH=/Users/sm/go #gosetup
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.18/libexec/bin/go mod tidy #gosetup
go: finding module for package github.com/annttu/latenssi-go/collector/config
go: finding module for package github.com/annttu/latenssi-go/probe/probe
go: finding module for package github.com/annttu/latenssi-go/proto
go: finding module for package github.com/annttu/latenssi-go/probe/config
go: finding module for package github.com/annttu/latenssi-go/probe/grpc
go: finding module for package github.com/annttu/latenssi-go/collector/destination
go: finding module for package github.com/annttu/latenssi-go/collector/grpc
go: finding module for package github.com/annttu/latenssi-go/probe/result
go: finding module for package github.com/miekg/dns
go: found github.com/miekg/dns in github.com/miekg/dns v1.1.48
go: finding module for package github.com/annttu/latenssi-go/probe/result
go: finding module for package github.com/annttu/latenssi-go/collector/config
go: finding module for package github.com/annttu/latenssi-go/probe/probe
go: finding module for package github.com/annttu/latenssi-go/probe/config
go: finding module for package github.com/annttu/latenssi-go/collector/destination
go: finding module for package github.com/annttu/latenssi-go/probe/grpc
go: finding module for package github.com/annttu/latenssi-go/collector/grpc
go: finding module for package github.com/annttu/latenssi-go/proto
github.com/annttu/lantenssi-go/src/github.com/annttu/latenssi-go/collector imports
    github.com/annttu/latenssi-go/collector/config: module github.com/annttu/latenssi-go@latest found (v0.0.0-20180822071121-cbe7dd3b5c65), but does not contain package github.com/annttu/latenssi-go/collector/config
github.com/annttu/lantenssi-go/src/github.com/annttu/latenssi-go/collector imports
    github.com/annttu/latenssi-go/collector/destination: module github.com/annttu/latenssi-go@latest found (v0.0.0-20180822071121-cbe7dd3b5c65), but does not contain package github.com/annttu/latenssi-go/collector/destination
github.com/annttu/lantenssi-go/src/github.com/annttu/latenssi-go/collector imports
    github.com/annttu/latenssi-go/collector/grpc: module github.com/annttu/latenssi-go@latest found (v0.0.0-20180822071121-cbe7dd3b5c65), but does not contain package github.com/annttu/latenssi-go/collector/grpc
github.com/annttu/lantenssi-go/src/github.com/annttu/latenssi-go/collector/destination imports
    github.com/annttu/latenssi-go/proto: module github.com/annttu/latenssi-go@latest found (v0.0.0-20180822071121-cbe7dd3b5c65), but does not contain package github.com/annttu/latenssi-go/proto
github.com/annttu/lantenssi-go/src/github.com/annttu/latenssi-go/probe imports
    github.com/annttu/latenssi-go/probe/config: module github.com/annttu/latenssi-go@latest found (v0.0.0-20180822071121-cbe7dd3b5c65), but does not contain package github.com/annttu/latenssi-go/probe/config
github.com/annttu/lantenssi-go/src/github.com/annttu/latenssi-go/probe imports
    github.com/annttu/latenssi-go/probe/grpc: module github.com/annttu/latenssi-go@latest found (v0.0.0-20180822071121-cbe7dd3b5c65), but does not contain package github.com/annttu/latenssi-go/probe/grpc
github.com/annttu/lantenssi-go/src/github.com/annttu/latenssi-go/probe imports
    github.com/annttu/latenssi-go/probe/probe: module github.com/annttu/latenssi-go@latest found (v0.0.0-20180822071121-cbe7dd3b5c65), but does not contain package github.com/annttu/latenssi-go/probe/probe
github.com/annttu/lantenssi-go/src/github.com/annttu/latenssi-go/probe/grpc imports
    github.com/annttu/latenssi-go/probe/result: module github.com/annttu/latenssi-go@latest found (v0.0.0-20180822071121-cbe7dd3b5c65), but does not contain package github.com/annttu/latenssi-go/probe/result
```

Comment: There is no single way or receipt of doing this.

Comment: @Volker I'm asking how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Starts with [`go mod init`](https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-mod-init)

```
cd /path/to/latenssi-go
go mod init github.com/annttu/latenssi-go
go mod tidy
```

For a fork, add a [replace directive](https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-mod-file-replace) to avoid modifying the sources:

```
replace github.com/annttu/latenssi-go => github.com/samip5/latenssi-go
```

Note: the [original project `annttu/latenssi-go`](https://github.com/annttu/latenssi-go) has its sources in `src/`: that won't work.

You need your sources directly at the root project level, not under `src`.
[`src` is only used by GOPATH](https://go.dev/ref/mod#minimal-module-compatibility) when building `GOPATH` mode (pre-Go v1.11).

Comment: That much I do have. but that go mod tidy is the one that's failing.

Comment: @samip537 First make sure you have initialized with the right name `github.com/annttu/latenssi-go`. Second, you might need to tag and push a v0.1.0 semver tag, if I understand https://stackoverflow.com/a/70886948/6309.

Comment: Hmm, I did fork it and try to push a semvar but didin't help? https://github.com/samip5/latenssi-go/tree/v0.1.0

Comment: @samip537 I did not realize you had to fork the project. For testing, can you then change the `go.mod` to reflect the new path `github.com/samip5/latenssi-go`, and change any import from `github.com/annttu/...` to `github.com/samip5/...`, just to see if that works better? That won't be a regular fork anymore though.

Comment: I did do those, when I pushed it. go.mod has the new path and all paths were changed to reflect it.

Comment: Using the `replace` directive in the `go.mod` can be handy to build from a fork but avoid having to update source imports that point to the original git repo path.

Comment: @colm.anseo good point. I have included a replace directive in the answer.

Comment: The issue seems to be that there is no module, even though it's using a path like github.com/samip5/latenssi-go/probe/result. Which indeed doesn't appear to be a module?

Comment: @samip537 The actual issue is the packages are in src. Delete src, move the packages one level up and that should work.

Comment: @VonC Doesn't seem to fix it. :(

Comment: @samip537 Actually, when you see for instance `import github.com/samip5/latenssi-go/probe/config`, that means you should have in your repo a folder `probe/config`, not `github.com/samip5/latenssi-go/probe/config`

Comment: @VonC I do know that much that go project structure usually has src, bin and pkg in project root.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244212/discussion-between-vonc-and-samip537).